# How to do a join on 2 tables, but only return the data for one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if this is possible. But is it possible to do a join on 2 tables, but return the data for only one of the tables. I want to join the two tables based on a condition, but I only want the data for one of the tables. Is this possible with SQL, if so how? After reading the docs, it seems that when you do a join you get the data for both tables. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get data from both tables because join is based on **"[Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)"** + **"[Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(relational_algebra))"**. But after the join, you can do a **"[Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Projection_(%CF%80))"** with desired columns.

SQL has an easy syntax for this:

```
Select t1.*               --taking data just from one table
from one_table t1
inner join other_table t2
on t1.pk = t2.fk
```

You can chose the table through the alias: `t1.*` or `t2.*`. The symbol `*` means "all fields".

Also you can include `where` clause, `order by` or other join types like `outer join` or `cross join`.

Comment: Thanks, its too soon. Ill give you the green checkmark soon.

Answer (score 1):

A typical SQL query has multiple clauses.

The `SELECT` clause mentions the columns you want in your result set.

The `FROM` clause, which includes `JOIN` operations, mentions the tables from which you want to retrieve those columns.

The `WHERE` clause filters the result set.

The `ORDER BY` clause specifies the order in which the rows in your result set are presented.

There are a few other clauses like `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT`. You can read about those.

To do what you ask, select the columns you want, then mention the tables you want. Something like this.

```
   SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.address
     FROM t1
     JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

This gives you data from `t1` from rows that match `t2`.

**Pro tip:**  Avoid the use of `SELECT *`.  Instead, mention the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

This would typically be done using `exists` (or `in`) if you prefer:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 on t2.x = t1.y);
```

Although you can use `join`, it runs the risk of multiplying the number of rows in the result set -- if there are duplicate matches in `table2`.  There is no danger of such duplicates using `exists` (or `in`).  I also find the logic to be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

If you join on 2 tables.

You can use **SELECT** to select the data you want

If you want to get a table of data, you can do this,just select one table date

```
SELECT b.title
FROM blog b
JOIN type t ON b.type_id=t.id;
```

If you want to get the data from two tables, you can do this,select two table date.

```
SELECT b.title,t.type_name
FROM blog b
JOIN type t ON b.type_id=t.id;
```